# Django makemigrations not detecting project/apps/myapp

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

**Solved**

Interesting:

- `./manage.py makemigrations apps.myapp` -> "App 'apps.myapp' could
  not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?"
- `./manage.py makemigrations myapp` -> Works.
- `./manage.py makemigrations` -> "No changes detected" (it does detect changes if myapp is in the project root)

**Original question:**

Project structure

```
myproject/
    myproject/
    apps/
        myapp/
            __init__.py
            admin.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            views.py
            tests.py
        myapp2/
        myapp3/
        __init__.py
    static/
    templates/
    virtualenv/
    manage.py
```

myproject/apps/myapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'apps.myapp',
    'apps.myapp2',
    'apps.myapp3',
]
```

`makemigrations` cannot find "myapps" that's not in the project root.
At the same time, `migrate` does find it.

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations apps.myapp
App 'apps.myapp' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

$ ./manage.py migrate apps.myapp
CommandError: App 'apps.myapp' does not have migrations.
```

Isn't the "let's put our apps into an apps folder" practise valid any more, am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug of the `makemigrations` command?

*Note1: before running `makemigrations`, I removed the "migrations" folder of myapp, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. It did get re-created when the app was in the project root.*

*Note2: I did research google and stackoverflow, I only found similar questions where the solution was either "adding the app to settings.py", "running makemigrations before migrate" or "some migration issue between Django 1.6 and 1.7". None of these apply to my situation, I think.*

Comment: RE: Note1, yes it matters - if there is no migrations folder, it will not create one nor will it create migrations.

Comment: It does create the migrations folder if myapp is in the project root.

Comment: I started a new app, moved under the "apps" directory, it has "migrations" folder. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: did u pass app_label in Meta class: if pass then u have to give app_label also.

Answer (score 29):

You may have deleted the migrations folder inside the app or `__init__.py` inside the `<app>/migrations/` folder, create a new one

```
myproject/
apps/
    myapp/
        migrations/
            __init__.py
```

You can always do makemigrations seperately without doing the above step

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Answer (score 7):

try

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'myproject.apps.myapp',
]
```

and

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Comment: Tried: `ImportError: No module named 'myproject.apps'`

Comment: Could you get more specific? Which part of my settings shall I share so you better see what might be wrong about it?

Comment: Had the same issue, posted answer is correct. If you are getting an import error try 'python manage.py shell' to get more detail about the error.

Comment: Why we have to use `myproject` as prefixer? Why not django can find the apps in apps folder?

Answer (score 1):

It's works now. It didn't work before because I didn't make any changes to my model.
I'm new to django and was trying to execute the command from the videos I watched. Django documentation tells you that makemigrations create new migrations based on the changes you made to your model. So, I make changes in models.py and admin.py and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding "migrations" file into the app folders.